# Uploading files: Access to path denied

Tags: asp.net

I've given IUSR full control over the folder but when i upload files it gives me this error:
 Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\Desert.jpg' is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\Desert.jpg' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.


Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace:


[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\Desert.jpg' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7716783
   System.IO.File.Delete(String path) +7577512
   ASP.vivaweb_dwzupload_resizeaspnet_aspx.ResizeImage(String oldPathImage, String newPathImage, Int32 Width, Int32 Height, Int32 imgQuality, Boolean keep, Boolean isThumb) +217
   ASP.vivaweb_dwzupload_resizeaspnet_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +379
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: are you using source control?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear your application is using "ASP.NET" user

So give permission to this user or simply give permission to user **everyone**

Comment: no my godaddy windows plesk server, you can't find "EVERYONE" on the users list, when i do it on my local machine by assigning rights to "EVERYONE" is works, but i don't know how to do it on the windows plesk hosting

Answer (score 0):

There are a few unanswered questions in this post that I'll have to make a few assumptions on. First, I have no idea how you have your site deployed and thus don't know what identity it's using. If you are running it directly through visual studio, depending on your version, it should be either using ["ApplicationPoolIdenity" or "NetworkService"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx).

If you are running your site through IIS, you can figure that out easily (and change it if you like). Just open up application pools under the IIS instance and you should see them in an "identity" column.

After that, you will need to make sure to give permissions the same as the identity used to your site. Get the root folder used to house the site and give it appropriate permissions. Right click the folder and go to Properties -> Security -> Edit. Add in the identity that your site is using and you should be done.

A final note, you may actually want to turn on the debug configuration setting in your web.config file if you are in a local/debugging environment. It will give more information to work with to solve your issue.

Comment: making it work locally for me its really simple by just giving everyone full control and it works. now the problem is how to make it work online cos there's no "EVERYONE" in the given users on the hosting server. i don't know if it can be done through web.config

Comment: Did you try adding in the permissions for either of those entities? You probably don't want everyone to have full permissions with your files anyway. The default IIS accounts are "LocalService" "LocalSystem" "NetworkService" and "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Try those first. 

I also found this with a quick google search (how to set plesk permissions). Not sure if it's what you need: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6481/setting-directory-permissions-with-windows-hosting-accounts

Comment: thanks for you zeal to help but on the godaddy plesk server there is no network service and Applicationpoolidentity found there